# homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist launchctl load error

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I brew installed mysql and want to launchd start mysql at login.

```
brew install mysql
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

The brew install was successful, but after the last command, it shows

```
Could not find domain for
```

How to resolve this issue?

System info: Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite, brew installed `mysql-5.6.21`.

On my other machine (same OS, newer and less used), the above three commends were successful and mysql indeed automatically start after restarting the machine.

Comment: stuck with same issue, for a different plist though. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 40):

The user running the command must be logged in via the GUI. Then, the command will work over both SSH and with a local terminal on the machine.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using a vagrant and trying out [laptop](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) a thoughtbot configuration management project which among other things tries to install postgresql and redis, which were both breaking. After manually going into the GUI from VirtualBox, it worked, see this [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop/issues/469)

Comment: OS X is driving me mad with insane crap like this

Comment: is there any method to login the GUI via ssh? Imagine login in a remote computer.

Comment: This will also work if you use automatic login and then log in as the same user over SSH. I used this successfully for a macOS guest that was provisioned with Vagrant.

Comment: All I needed to do in Vagrant was run it as sudo, i.e.   sudo brew services start redis

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue when I was trying to start postgresql after installing it via homebrew, although previously it had worked fine.  I later realised that it only failed when run remotely via SSH - when I used a local terminal it began without problems.

Answer (score 3):

Re [DanielaWaranie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924079/678951): sudo should **not** be necessary.

Remove the original plist and create the link again:

```
$ rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

$ brew services start mysql
```

I had the same issue. For some reason the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` file was not a symbolic link but a regular file. After removing the file and creating the link again it worked fine.

Comment: Removing the plist doesn't work for me. Running "brew services start name-of-service" replaces the symlink with a plain file again, and at least "ps uax" fails to see any started service. I log in as a non-admin user, but have a terminal tab open for my admin user. I also run macos High Sierra, problems might have started after that. What _does_ work though is "sudo brew services start name-of-service", I would rather not run e.g. mongodb as root however (mariadb does change user to _mysql, as intended, when started as root).

Answer (score 2):

This error message is missleading. Most common reason for this issue **is a permission problem**.

Just run it as root:

```
sudo su
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

I had the same issue on Mac OS X El Capitan when running with a restricted user using a interactive, non-login shell or an interactive, login shell. Works in a sh and bash.

Comment: The sudo should not be necessary. Remove the plist file.